# Custom input iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a custom read-only data structure that I need to transverse. I would like to create a custom iterator that need to skip certain values.

A simple but equivalent example would be the following. I have a vector of numbers and I want to loop through all skipping the negative values. Normally I would do something like:

```
vector<int> v;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it > 0) {
       dosomething(*it);
    }
}
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
vector<int> v;
for (vector<int>::my_iterator it = v.my_begin(); it!=v.my_end(); ++it) {
    dosomething(*it);
}
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: As a very first step, I'd take a look at the [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library, and especially at [`iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html).

Comment: ...as well as boost::filter_iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily achieved with a [`boost::filter_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html), if your data structure already stores a container under the hood. Here's a simple example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

class X{
    typedef std::vector<int> container;
    struct Pred{
        bool operator()(int i){
            return i % 2 == 0;
        }
    };

public:
    typedef boost::filter_iterator<Pred, container::iterator> iterator;

    void add(int val){ nums.push_back(val); }
    iterator begin(){ return iterator(nums.begin(), nums.end()); }
    iterator end(){ return iterator(nums.end(), nums.end()); }

private:
    container nums;
};

int main(){
    X x;
    for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        x.add(i);
    for(X::iterator it = x.begin(), ite = x.end(); it != ite; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
}
```

[Live example at Ideone.](http://ideone.com/xuX5R) Output:

> 0 2 4 6 8

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a very nice solution, but I'll post it anyway. Any attempt to dereference this iterator wrapper will cause it to check the current value and advance the iterator past any negative values. It will be called recur

```
template<typename InputIterator>
struct nonnegative_iterator : InputIterator {
        template<typename Arg>
        nonnegative_iterator(Arg i) : InputIterator(i) {
        }
        typename InputIterator :: reference operator* () {
            typename InputIterator :: reference x = InputIterator :: operator*();
            if( x < 0) {
                    ++ (*this); // equivalent to this -> operator++ ()
                    return **this;
            } else 
                    return x;
        }
};
```

which can be used like this:

```
 for ( nonnegative_iterator< vector<int>::iterator > it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
```

This has some problems, for example I haven't implemented a `const` method to allow to dereference to `value_type`. So use at your own risk!

Comment: It also won't work if the iterator type to be adapted happens to be a pointer type. I'm not sure if `std::vector<T>::iterator` is required to be a class type in C++2011. In C++2003 it was certainly allowed to implement this type as a plain pointer but this may have been changed.

Comment: Good point, @DietmarKühl. Maybe my solution could be changed to have the InputIterator being merely a member of my class, rather than as a base class. But that's inconvenient, as it would require us to write all the methods that are supported by an iterator. So now I have a question: what operators should be supported by an iterator? dereference (`*`), prefix and postfix increment and decrement, and copy-assignment and copy-construction. Anything else?

Comment: Apart from the operations you also need a number of typedefs or use `std::iterator<...>` as a base. You also need the equality and inequality operators. If the value type happens to be a structure type you also need the member access `operator->()`. I think that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have control over the interface of `vector<int>`, e.g. because it is actually `std::vector<int>`, the first thing you want to do is to change the way you get your custom iterators. That is, instead of writing

```
for (vector<int>::my_iterator it = v.my_begin(); it != v.my_ned(); ++it)
```

you would use

```
for (my_iterator it(my_begin(v)), end(my_end(v)); it != end; ++it)
```

You can achieve the modified interface for a custom container but this is a bigger fish to fry. Creating your input iterator now essentially amounts to creating a suitable wrapper for the underlying iterator. This could look something like this:

```
template <typename InIt, Pred>
struct my_iterator {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::value_type      value_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::reference       reference;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIt>::pointer         pointer;
    my_iterator(InIt it, InIt end, Pred pred): it_(it), end_(end), pred_(pred) {}
    bool operator== (my_iterator const& other) const { reutrn this->it_ == other.it_; }
    bool operator!= (my_iterator const& other) const { return !(*this == other); }
    reference operator*() { return *this->it_; }
    pointer   operator->() { return this->it_; }
    my_iterator& operator++() {
        this->it_ = std::find_if(this->it_, this->end_, this->pred_);
        return *this;
    }
    my_iterator operator++(int)
    { my_iterator rc(*this); this->operator++(); return rc; }
private:
    InIt it_, end_;
    Pred pred_;
```

The `my_begin()` and `my_end()` functions would then create a suitable object of this type. One approach to avoid having to write this is to have a look a Boost's iterator adaptors: there should be something suitable over there.